# Update and query in single batch (one roundtrip) using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Is there currently a way to run an update statement and a query in one batch and have dapper map the results?

Example:

```
var queryString = @"UPDATE TABLE_A SET IsDeleted = 1; SELECT * FROM TABLE_A;"
IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(dbConnection);
return cnn.SomeMethod<List<TableAModel>>(sql);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It should just work. If you have two `SELECT` statements, or an `OUTPUT` in the `UPDATE` (in other words two resultsets) you can use `QueryMultiple`. I would generally recommend `OUTPUT` if you want to get the rows affected by the `UPDATE`. Also you need to dispose `cnn` with a `using`

Comment: @Charlieface I need a query that does not involve the `OUTPUT` values, like the second query in `queryString`. That being said, `QueryMultiple` will not work with the example in the post. I could always map the object returned from a built in `SqlClient` method and then map the result set(s) using dapper, but I was wondering if there is a way to skip a step.

Comment: Again, if you only have one resultset (no `OUTPUT` clause) it should just work like any other `SELECT` using `cnn.Query<TableAModel>(sql).ToList()`. What about it is not working?

Comment: @Charlieface I tried and the `cnn.Query...` only seems to work with `SELECT` and not `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. I was only able to get `UPDATE` and `INSERT` to work with `cnn.Execute...`

Comment: You obviously need *some* resultset to be returned, so it won't work with *just* `UPDATE`. Are you saying you had a single query batch of `UPDATE ...; SELECT ...;` and it didn't work?

Comment: @Charlieface correct. Has it worked for you?

Comment: Yes it works fine. Eg `conn.Query<int>("UPDATE Test SET N1 = 0; SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2;").ToList().Dump();` gets me a list of `1` `2`. Perhaps you have a trigger on the table being updated that is messing things up? Or please paste into your question your *actual* code (looks like you gave an example) along with any exception message

Comment: @Charlieface I made a rookie mistake. The api was set to `HttpGet` instead of post. Sometimes it's the small things xD. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@CharlieFace said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70329883/update-and-query-in-single-batch-one-roundtrip-using-dapper/70370973#comment124383065_70329883), the following will work just fine:

```cs
conn.Query<int>(
  "UPDATE Test SET N1 = 0; SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2;"
).ToList().Dump();
```